# Spring not registering @ManagedBean

Tags: java, spring, jetty, wicket

I am looking at building a web application using **wicket**, running on a **jetty** server, and want to use **spring** as IoC framework. To test this setup I made a small web app. I am having spring doing a component scan to look up my beans. The test app has only one such bean, annotated with **@ManagedBean**. An instance of this bean is injected into a wicket WebPage.

The problem is that this works on my development machine, using embedded jetty, but not on my production machine, running jetty as a service.

I have tracked the problem down up to **ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.registerDefaultFilters()**.

On my development machine filters are registered for:

- org.springframework.stereotype.Component
- javax.inject.Named
- javax.annotation.ManagedBean

My production machine only provides the first two, missing my @ManagedBean annotation.

First I thought maybe I was using a different version of ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider, but, using **-verbose:class**, showed that it is only loaded once, from spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar.

As a workaround I can annotate my beans with **@Component instead of @ManagedBean**, but would still like to know why the ManagedBean filter is not registered.

Even though verbose class loading seems to suggest otherwise I still suspect I am using different versions on my two machines.

If anyone can point me in the direction of a solution to this problem it would be greatly apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

My web page is as follows:

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@SpringBean
private SpringTestClass test;

public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
..
```

My bean is annotated as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
public class SpringTestClass {
```

Am am using:

- Jetty 9
- Spring 4.0.2
- Wicket 6.0

Comment: `@ManagedBean` is not an annotation processed by Spring.

Comment: Make sure that you use the same java version and dependencies… Depending on which java version the `@ManagedBean` might or might not be available.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `@ManagedBean` is supported when the package is detected. THis has been added as JEE6 support. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6465